# Can't bind to 'timetable' since it isn't a known property of 'app-timetable'

Tags: angular, typescript, https, components, ngmodel

this is my student-profile.component.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV0zt.png)

this is my timetable.component.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogphh.png)

this is my student-profile.ts [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntgBO.png)

ERROR->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSStQ.png)

After trying every possible way to debug this error, i am still getting the same error.

I have a file, data.json file and i wanted to output that data to my html page but not able to show the ouput of the json file on the webpage but still getting the output in my VSCODE console.

Comment: providing images will not help and will suffer with down votes so please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and go through [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a component (TimetableComponent)`app-timetable` in you standalone components HTML, then you need to add it to the imports array of `StudentProfileComponent`

```
...
@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, TimetableComponent],
  ...
})
export class StudentProfileComponent {
    ...
```